# Animation on View sizechanged

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to do animation around View that changes size due to setVisible on it's child.
I've got View like that:

```
<LinearLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:background="@drawable/roundedtable_filled"  
android:layout_margin="8dip"  
android:orientation="vertical">  
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/title"  
    style="@style/appInfoTextBold"  
    android:text="Jakie dane powinna uwzględniać reklamacja?" />  
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"  
    style="@style/appInfoText"  
    android:text="Kochasz kino? Z niecierpliwością czekasz na kolejne odcinki  swoich ulubionych seriali? Marzysz o przeprowadzce do Hollywood? Jeśli tak, to vod.onet.pl jest serwisem właśnie dla Ciebie." />  
</LinearLayout>
```

On *title* clicked I change Visibilisty of *text*. Now I'd like to have nice animation of growing size of my View. What's the correct way to do that?
Maybe I shouldn't change text visibility and instead try resize the view in thread so it would be bigger every 40ms or sth like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a ScaleAnimation that scales the view in from some fractional size to its full size. Start the animation at the same time as you set it visible. You might also want to fade it in (AlphaAnimation) so that it doesn't just blink in unless you're scaling up from a fraction of 0 (which would make it invisible because it has no size to begin with).
Scaling text never looks that great, but if the animation is quick it might be sufficient.

Comment: Thank's for reply, I abandon this animation. I tried sth like your way and it would work for single item but the issue is that this layout is item in listView, so what I've got is that after setVisible I have empty place and growing animation. That's exactly what you said on Google IO about animation framework, it just draw view differently, other part's of layout are not aware of it. So there is a lot of workaround to change my view actual size (size that is known for listView) and synchronize it with animation. BTW gr8 presentation on IO about new animation framework.

Comment: The new animation framework definitely makes this kind of stuff easier, although scaling a view (in the old or new system) still wouldn't alter its size as far as the layout is concerned. If you actually want to change the layout bounds, consider animating LayoutParams values (trickier in the old system, since all animations are specific to Views. Kinda have to hack around that fact). Or do the scale, then at the end change the layout to suit the new scaled size of the object. Note, also, that a 'scaled' view will not necessarily looked like a 'resized' view.